# Display only the date in java using a toString method

Tags: java, date, time, tostring, simpledateformat

I have a **Product class** and a **Main class**, each Product has a **date** variable. I'm setting the Date of every Product in the Main such as :

```
product1.date=setDate("2015/05/18");
```

The **setDate()** method has to take a Date or String variable as argument in that format and parse it into a Date so it can be set for the Product. I was using SimpleDateFormat but it's confusing because I want to do 2 things :

I have 2 problems:

1- How can I make it diplay only the date such as : 2015/05/10 and not the entire time zone and day of the week?

2- I'm using a **toString()** method in the Product class to display everything related to that object (ID, Label, price and date) how can I make the date be displayed using **toString()**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it this way:

```
public String toString(){

    SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd);

    String str = "";

    str += "Id: " + this.id + "\n";
    str += "Price: " + this.price + "\n";
    .
    .
    str += f.format(date);  

    return str;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about the hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds, and timezone, I suggest that you implement setDate to set the corresponding `Date` object to be the first hour, minute, second, millisecond, of that date in the GMT timezone.  Trust me, it will save you issues later on (also construct a new copy, and discard the input Date, as doing otherwise permits people to modify it at a distance)

To print out the date, use a SimpleDateFormat.  The format you want is "yyyy/MM/dd"  The M's are upper case because lowecase m is for minutes.